# preventing external page from redirecting MY (parent) page

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

Using the latest version of Chrome on Mac OS 10.7.

I assume it is some clever javascript that is enabling the folks at this webpage:

http://www.chairworks.com/

...to close my (the parent) page which opened their (chairworks.com) page in the first place.
I did not open them with javascript, but with an `<a>` tag with the `target="_blank"` attribute.

If I disable javascript, then the behavior stops.

```
<a href="http://www.chairworks.com" target="_blank">www.chairworks.com</a>
```

I would expect the page at chairworks.com/ to simply open in another tab/window... but what I find is that as soon as the new browser tab opens, it closes, and then *my* page (the parent tab/window) gets redirected to the chairworks.com page.

Kinda rude.

Can someone point me to what code enables them to do that?  And how do I prevent it?  (Assuming I want a link to behave as expected, such as in my demo page.)

Comment: I had no idea this behavior was possible. At first glance this seems like an awesome potential exploit.

Comment: Normal behavior, by spec. But indeed, this is rude. Even the first time I've seen this in the wild (and boy do I surf the corners of the web..) Maybe they just wanted to escape being embedded in frames, but this is insane. I would actually notify _management_ of this site. NOT the admin's/programmers. Explain to management that they are killing their own site. Then hope they'll fight it out with their coders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the script they are using:

```
setTimeout('redirect_page()',0);
function redirect_page(){if (window.opener) { window.opener.location.href = '/home.html'; window.close(); } else { location.href = '/home.html'; }}
```

As to how to circumvent it (just an idea):
Create your own blank page, with it's source set to about:blank. When it loads (or after a time-out) you could write some code to that window that will then open the offending link. 
Then the offending link just closes your buffer-page. F*ck 'm!! Power to the user!

Edit: looks like you could also name your page `home.html` hehe, but that is not such a workable solution..

**Final Edit:** *SIMPLE LOGIC people...*
`<a href="http://www.chairworks.com/home.html" target="_blank">www.chairworks.com</a>`
works for everyone, no javascript needed.
See this working [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/RmZDX/show/).

Answer (score 6):

I believe the proper thing to do is set corresponding link type attribute so the browser doesn't provide the target window with and `opener` reference.

```
<a href="https://untrusted-site.org" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">Link</a>
```

You can read more about link types here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

Answer (score 1):

As @GitaarLAB explained, the targeted website is using the `window.opener` property to get access to your page. Using some Javascript yourself, and an `about:blank` page in the middle, can help you cut their access to your page. It would be like:

```
 <a href="http://www.chairworks.com/" target="_blank" onclick="var w = window.open('about:blank'); w.opener = null; w.open('http://www.chairworks.com/'); return false;">http://www.chairworks.com/</a>
```

Some notes:

1. I'm leaving the `href` property there for users without JS enabled (guess what! the targeted website won't have JS neither! ;), or the web crawlers like search engines' (only those who don't care about JS stuff, though)
2. Before redirecting to the targeted website, you cut the back-link by resetting the `window.opener` attribute of the new window.
3. And after opening the targeted website, there's a `return false;` to prevent the normal the browser to use the `href` and `target` attributes.

Comment: To my knowledge, that code would **NOT work** as intended, as you have not read my answer correctly. You normally have no access to the new window/frame directly since the browser needs TIME to open a new window and LOAD the physical page `about:blank`.

Comment: Actually it works for me, as I tested it before posting it here. But I agree that the case you are referring to can actually happen. To make sure it doesn't happen, we would need to set an event listener on the new `about:blank` page, instead of setting/unsetting its properties directly right after opening it. Thanks for noting it.

Comment: That is exactly what I already explained hihi. Out of interest, what browser did you test it in?

Comment: It's Chrome (beta) on a fast Core i7 machine. I think users with slower ones might loose the new website completely.

Comment: By the way, let me note that IMO it's a security issue and `window.opener.url` SHOULD follow the *same-origin policy*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure of users having a chance to loose the new website completely haha. Spent over 2 weeks to get the correct technique down (for a high profile website). Anyway, let's hope our comments will wake-up future readers before blindly copy pasting a 'green' answer haha.

Comment: It's been my first time facing such a thing. Looks like you have more experience with it. Care about starting the discussion on Mozilla/Chromium bugzilla or a W3C mailing list?

Comment: you guys are both ahead of me here. Are you saying the security risk comes from behnam's answer/suggested code?  ..or that the security risk is simply inherent in chairworks.com's hack (that the browser even allows it) in the first place?

Comment: there is no security risk in behnam's suggested code. behnam is contemplating if the browser allowing this might be a security thing. @Behnam: I'm still not sure if I consider this behavior to be a security bug: the simplest solution is: not using their website, or linking directly their `home.html` like so: `<a href="http://www.chairworks.com/home.html" target="_blank">www.chairworks.com</a>` working [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/RmZDX/show/)  Over the last year I've also become pretty weary on posting 'bug-reports' to Mozilla, thanks for the invite tough! I'll update my answer.

Comment: this answer did work for all browsers I tested (Chrome/FF on Mac/PC, Safari on Mac)... *except* for IE9.  Of course @GitaarLAB's answer makes the most sense though.